# SVG icon disappears when collapsing a sidebar

Tags: html, css, svg

When I collapse my sidebar I want the text to hide and keep the SVG visible.

It works as expected but for some reason when the sidebar is collapsed, the SVG of 'Projects' disappears (the other svg's are displayed as expected)

What I've tried:

CSS (truncated)

Added a rule to don't show the `Projects` text when the sidebar is collapsed (not working)

```
#sidebar.active #sidebarProjectsText{
    display: none;
}
```

Added a rule to `display: block` the svg when the sidebar is active or not active (not working)

```
#sidebar #projectsSvg,
#sidebar.active #projectsSvg {
    display: block;
}
```

Desired output:

- Text `Projects` and arrow disappear when collapsing
- Svg image visible always regardless the state of the sidebar (active or not active)

[LIVE JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/gerasg/7wtzo4xL/150/)

what am I doing wrong?

UPDATE with Nimeshka Srimal answer:

I tried to apply the suggestion of Nimeshka Srimal but then, when toggling the sidebar the svg image gets smaller. It solved my problem but it created a new one.

[image]

[JS FIDDLE with Nimeshka Srimal answer implemented](https://jsfiddle.net/gerasg/7wtzo4xL/152/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your styles are applied to the `.sidebar-item` class and your project menu item does not have that class.

Just wrap it with a `<div>` or `<span>` and add the `.sidebar-item` class.

```
<div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
  <h5 class="mb-0 d-flex flex-nowrap">
    <svg id="projectsSvg" ...></svg>
    <div class="sidebar-item">
      <button
        id="btnProjectsSidebar"
        ...
      >
        <span id="sidebarProjectsText text-nowrap">Projects</span>
        <i id="profile-chevron-down" class="bi bi-chevron-down ml-2"> </i>
      </button>
    </div>
  </h5>
</div>
```

You might need to fix the other styles.

Answer to the updated question:
Provide a fixed width to the svg icons.

Ex:

```
.sidebar-element svg {
  min-width: 55px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, before accepting your answer I observed that the svg image gets smaller...what could it be?

Comment: what do you mean by "svg image gets smaller" ?

Comment: I edited my question and added a new fiddle with your suggestion implemented for your convenience. Basically for no reason the svg image is resized after toggling.

Comment: Provide a fixed width to the svg elements to fix it. I have updated the answer.